# Android 4.2: Normal widget to lockscreen widget

Tags: android, widget, lockscreen

Easy question: I have just created an analog clock widget with eclipse, now I'd just like to make this widget be a lockscreen widget, too. I want this widget to be used with the new lockscreen widget feature in android 4.2
I am no programmer yet, so please, specify the line of code to use and the file where to put it, thank you :)

Comment: GabMus, please before ask anything, show us what are you tried for. We will be very happy to help you as long as you show something to solve your problem by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line to your `appwidget-provider`:

```
android:widgetCategory="home_screen|keyguard"
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html